# Rider not warning for incorrect namespaces for Unity Runtime assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rider

For a while now I have been having trouble with rider warnings for incorrect namespace.

I have two assemblies for my unity project, one for the Editor, the other for the Runtime
Both namespace have the same root namespace.
Essentially I have:

Editor assembly: `Unity.Something.Editor`
Runtime assembly: `Unity.Something.Runtime`

Root namespace: `Unity.Something`

If an Editor class is located under the folder Toto, namespace will warn about the namespace should be: `Unity.Something.Editor.Toto`, which is what I expect. I would expect `Unity.Something.Runtime.Toto` in under the Runtime assembly.

When a namespace in the Editor assembly is incorrect, rider warns about correcting it.
When a namespace in the Runtime assembly is incorrect, rider does not warn about it

What could be causing this behaviour ?